Click to activate only working in half the window
I'm trying out Trumbowyg, and while it's working very well, there's an issue when it comes to clicking inside it to 'activate' it (i.e. show the cursor) to be able to start typing.
It only activates if I click in the top 40% of the window. If I click on the lower part, it doesn't activate. A screenshot makes it easier to explain, I've added two colored boxes on the screenshot; if I click in the green area, the cursors appears and I can start typing. If I click in the red area, nothing happens:

When nothing happens, it can lead to a user thinking it doesn't work.
Is there any way to fix this, so that I can click anywhere in the window to activate it?
The code I've used is very straightforward:
<form>
 <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="trumbowyg/trumbowyg.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="trumbowyg/ui/trumbowyg.min.css">
<script>
$('#comment').trumbowyg();
</script>

Please help!
Thank you.

Likely a div that is overlaying that part. Right-click the red area and choose "inspect" then look when you move over the html in the inspect window if there is something overlaying the editor. If you click [edit] and then the button [<>] you can create a [mcve] using CDN

@mplungjan the only code on that page is the code I pasted above, and I'm using vanilla Trumbowyg. However, following your advice I found this in the CSS:
.trumbowyg-box .trumbowyg-editor{max-height:100%;margin:0 auto}
I changed it to:
.trumbowyg-box .trumbowyg-editor{height: 230px;margin:0 auto}
And it solved the problem.
